# Is it true that $f'(\xi_1)(\xi_1-a)+f'(\xi_2)(\xi_2-b)+f(a)+f(b)=0$ if some conditions are met?

Tags: calculus, examples-counterexamples

**Problem**: if function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, and
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$$
Prove that there exists two distinct real numbers $\xi_1,\xi_2\in(a,b)$ such that
$$f'(\xi_1)(\xi_1-a)+f'(\xi_2)(\xi_2-b)+f(a)+f(b)=0$$

---

I suspect I should use some sort of mean value theorem to prove this problem, but I tried all forms of the theorem listed on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) without any success. I am beginning to suspect this problem might be wrong and am looking for counter-example. Any help from you is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a source for this problem? I'm asking myself why you think the mean value theorem is applicable, for example : is it because you recently learned it, or because the place from where you got the problem suggested it? It may happen that this problem needs a bigger hammer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Because the problem is given $\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$ so I conclude that there exists at least one point $x_0\in(a,b)$ such that $f(x_0)=0$, and I naively think it should have something to do with the mean value theorem. I could be wrong. This problem comes from a calculus problem set, in which it does not given any context. So I think all the conditions have been mentioned in the problem statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $f(x) = x^{10}-1$ on the interval $[0,11^{1/10}]$, it meets all your conditions;

Given that $f(0) +f(11^{1/10}) = 9$ and $f'(x) = 10x^9$ we are trying to find $\alpha,\beta \in (0,11^{1/10})$ such that

$$10\alpha^{10}+10\beta^9(\beta-11^{1/10}) +9 = 0 $$

but notice that $10\beta^9(\beta-11^{1/10}) +9$ is always positive (and also $10\alpha^{10}$ obviously) so the theorem is not true!

---

The way I found it :

I started to reason about $\cos x$ and $\arcsin x$ but then I realized that  this "type" of  functions attained the same derivative two times and they were also too symmetrical. Therefore I tried $x^2-1$ to avoid the problem but it wasn't strong enough (one of the two parts in which I also decomposed the expression resulting from $x^{10}-1$ was negative) then I tried $\alpha x^k + \beta$ and there were many counter-examples :-)

Comment: Awesome job! How on earth did you come up with $x^{10}-1$?

Comment: thank you @Alann Rosas ! I updated with the way I've found it!